# Uninstalling unwanted keyboard layout through magic

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11, keyboard-layout

UPD: see the answer for solution, don't bother with my sad story.

When I try to enter characters like ~ or ^ I don't see them right away, they are hidden. Instead, if I continue to type, I'm getting all those ã and ô characters. This disrupts typing and is annoying.

The keyboard layout in Windows reads as "ENG - English (United States), United States international" in the taskbar. There is no entry for it, however, in the Time & Language settings. If I install the "ENG - English (United States), United States" language pack, then, WHEN I switch to it, all my ~ and ^ are typed normally. But I still can't get rid of the "International" layout.

I cannot install this "international" layout and then remove it, and it doesn't even shows up when executing powershell command Get-WinUserLanguageList, I only see a single entry:

```
LanguageTag     : en-US
Autonym         : English (United States)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (United States)
ScriptName      : Latin
InputMethodTips : {0409:00000409}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

So how can I get rid of it?

The most annoying part is that it wasn't like this right away, no, the layout I don't need was added at some moment without any actions from my side.

Answer (score 0):

So, surprisingly, I've found a solution right away, but it's not an obvious one, not entirely at least.

1. Do the following in powershell:

   PS C:> $1 = New-WinUserLanguageList en-US

   PS C:> $1.Add("optional-LOCALE") // though it appears to be necessary, see  further

   PS C:> Set-WinUserLanguageList $1
2. Reboot.
3. See how after the reboot the UI language switched to en-US (i.e. to the first entry of the new list), but the unwanted layout is still there.
4. Pull some more hair if there is any left.
5. Change the Windows UI language from en-US to the optional-LOCALE you've (hopefully) added in step 1. Sign out.
6. Sign in again. WHOOSH! The unwanted locale is (hopefully) gone. How? Magic.
7. Now you can try to switch the UI language back if you need to and remove the "optional" locale (through the common language settings menu, not necessary the PS commands), reboot and report here about the result, because I ain't doing this step, no sir.
8. While the magic is there, go to the "Administrative language settings", "Copy settings" and apply the layouts you currently have to the administrative accounts, welcome screen and new user accounts.